# Prove the following inequality: $\sum^n_{k=1} (k-1)^3 < \frac{n^4}{4}<\sum^n_{k=1} k^3$

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove the following inequality:

$$\sum^n_{k=1} (k-1)^3 < \frac{n^4}{4}<\sum^n_{k=1} k^3$$

**Attempt:**

By induction, we have:

Base Case: $$(1-1)^3< \frac{1^4}{4}< 1^3$$

Inductive step:

Assume it's true for $n=k$, then

Thesis:

$$\sum^k_{a=1}a^3 < \frac{(k+1)^4}{4}<\sum^{k+1}_{a=1} (a+1)^3$$

Demonstration:

If $\frac{k^4}{4}<\sum^{k}_{a=1} a^3,$ then
$$\frac{(k-1)^4+4k^3}{4}<\sum^k_{a=1}(a-1)^3 < \frac{k^4}{4}$$
Adding $k^3$ on both sides, we have:
$$\frac{(k-1)^4+4k^3}{4}<\sum^{k+1}_{a=1}(a+1)^3+ k^3 < \frac{ k^4+4k^3}{4}$$
$$(k-1)^4<k^4$$

I got here, but I don't know what to go on, or if it concludes anything. I would like help

Comment: To prove the induction you don't need to prove  $\sum^k_{a=1}a^3 < \frac{(k+1)^4}{4}<\sum^{k+1}_{a=1} (a+1)^3$, but $\sum^{k+1}_{a=1}(a-1)^3 < \frac{(k+1)^4}{4}<\sum^{k+1}_{a=1} a^3$

Comment: Also, it's confusing having $k$ in your question statement *and* in "Assume it's true for $n=k$". One way to remedy this would be to instead, say:

$$$$

Assume it's true for $n=m$, then
$$$$
Thesis:

$$\sum^{m+1}_{k=1}(k-1)^3 < \frac{(m+1)^4}{4}<\sum^{m+1}_{k=1} k^3$$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2630761/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318357/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5En_%7Bk%3D1%7D%20(k-1)%5Ep%20%3C%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E%7Bp%2B1%7D%7D%7Bp%2B1%7D%3C%5Csum%5En_%7Bk%3D1%7D%20k%5Ep%24)

Comment: @Martin R You continue to destroy our forum. This problem is not duplicate. Topic starter does not want a solution by induction only.  In my solution I did not use induction.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Is *is* a duplicate in my opinion. I linked to four Q&As where the problem (for general exponent $p$) is solved with different methods, with and without induction.

Comment: I agree with @MartinR that the first question linked is a better duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Clayton: Please vote to close as a duplicate so that others can chime it. I cannot vote again because my initial duplicate vote had been reverted by another gold-badge holder.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The question does not say anything about the proof method. They got stuck with induction, but that is not the same as not wanting a solution by induction only! Moreover, considering they used the "induction" tag, it is reasonable to assume they *do* want a proof by induction.

Answer (score 1):

If you know calculus, then observe that
$$\frac{n^4}{4} = \int_0^n x^3\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k-1}^k x^3\,dx.$$
Since $x^3$ is an increasing function, it holds
$$(k-1)^3 < \int_{k-1}^kx^3\,dx < k^3,$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)^3 < \frac{n^4}{4} < \sum_{k=1}^n k^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},$$ which we can prove by the telescoping summation.

Indeed, $$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^2-k^2-1)=\frac{1}{2}((n+1)^2-1-n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2};$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^3-k^3-3k-1)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\left((n+1)^3-1-\frac{3n(n+1)}{2}-n\right)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^4-k^4-6k^2-4k-1)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left((n+1)^4-1-\frac{6n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{4n(n+1)}{2}-n\right)=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{(n-1)^2n^2}{4}<\frac{n^4}{4}<\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},$$ which is obvious.